# Can a shove give an Opportunity Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, forced-movement

For example, the shield mastery feat gives the option to shove an adjacent creature 5ft as a bonus action. Could you make an Opportunity Attack on the creature because it leaves your threat range without using the disengage action?

Comment: Relate: [Does Sentinel's opportunity attack trigger when I shove someone?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56481/does-sentinels-opportunity-attack-trigger-when-i-shove-someone)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### No.

From page 74 of the Basic Rules (also PHB p.195, or this [SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Opportunity-Attacks) site):

> **Opportunity Attacks**
>
> [...] You can avoid provoking an opportunity attack by taking the Disengage action. **You also don’t provoke an opportunity attack** when you teleport or **when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.** For example, you don’t provoke an opportunity attack if an explosion hurls you out of a foe’s reach or if gravity causes you to fall past an enemy.

If a creature *is moved* out of the threatened area (passive), rather than actively move (using its *own* action, movement or reaction), it does not provoke an Opportunity Attack.

Comment: +1 and The real world analog to this is, if you leave an active fight without focusing on the fight you are basically leaving yourself open. The disengage action is a fight action, where you leave the fight while paying full attention to what's going on. Being shoved is a sudden thing, and usually no one will have time to react to get a hit landed.